# Конкретная очистка через collectgarbage

Tags: lua, сборщик-мусора

Я не совсем понимаю, как работает collectgarbage(), сколько бы не читал мануалы. Дело в том, что я активно работаю с таблицами и порой приходится их полностью очищать через циклы или ещё чем-нибудь. Всё это занимает уйму времени и место в коде соответственно. После использования collectgarbage многие переменные, если не все, попросту пропадают и я ничего не могу с этим поделать. Можно ли как-то направить GC в нужное русло?

Пример проблемного кода:

```
local sometable = {name = "hello", value=1}
sometable = nil
collectgarbage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код совершенно корректен. Что в нём происходит:

```
local sometable = {name = "hello", value=1}
```

Очевидно, создаётся таблица с двумя значениями.

```
sometable = nil
```

В переменную записывается `nil`. Теперь таблица и её содержимое вам более недоступны.

```
collectgarbage()
```

Lua поизводит полный цикл сборки мусора, проверяя доступность структур данных и уничтожая недоступные.

> После использования `collectgarbage` многие переменные, если не все, попросту пропадают и я ничего не могу с этим поделать.

Если проблема исчезает при удалении **именно `collectgarbage`**, то это звучит как баг в движке Lua.

Я дополню ответ, если вы объясните, что код в примере должен делать по-вашему.

Comment: Теперь я понимаю работу сборщика мусора лучше, но остался последний вопрос, связанный с ним - какова область видимости у сборщика? Допустим в следующем коде:
https://pastebin.com/vdW6BfAU
Сборщик пройдётся циклом по функции, под которой находится или же я ошибаюсь

Comment: Сборщик мусора не знает такой вещи, как область видимости. Он просто удаляет все данные, **к которым у вас нет доступа**. **В 99% процентах случаев вам не нужен ручной вызов `collectgarbage()`**. Сборщик мусора тихо работает в фоне, подчищая данные, к которым вы не имеете доступа (у вас нет на них ссылки через переменную/таблицу/замыкание/прочее).

Comment: Понял. И последний вопросик - если я просто сделаю `sometable = nil` вместо цикла с присваиванием каждому значению таблицы nil или запуска очистки мусора, правильно ли я поступлю в этом случае?

Comment: Что вы хотите конкретно сделать? Если вы покидаете область видимости, это то же самое, что присвоение всем переменным из неё `nil`. Очистка мусора вас вообще не должна тревожить, это технические детали. Мне кажется, проще начать чат (тут есть такая возможность), чтобы ответить на любые вопросы, которые у вас остались.

Comment: Думаю это разумное решение. Основной вопрос решён, но хотелось бы обсудить детали уже моего личного недопонимания =d. Думаю [здесь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) можно это обсудить

Comment: Предлагаю продолжить в приватном чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96930/lua---